# Unable to send emails notification (not from gmail) from redmine bitnami

Tags: ubuntu, redmine, bitnami

Redmine - Ubuntu 14.04 on VM downloaded from: 
https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/virtual-machine 64-bit version

My configuration.yml consist:

```
default:
email_delivery:
        delivery_method: :smtp
        smtp_settings:
          openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
          enable_starttls_auto: false
          address: mail.e-bielsko.net
          port: '465'
          #domain: mail.e-bielsko.net
          authentication: :plain
          user_name: user
          password: "pass"
```

or second conf:

```
    email_delivery:
      delivery_method: :sendmail
```

if a have such configuration redmine doesnt start. I have  such an error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

apache2 last error_log:
http://pastebin.com/thyw66pn

Configuration with gmail works.

How to use eg.: sendmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added ***ssl: true***, so my config now looks:

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: false
      address: "mail.e-bielsko.net"
      port: '465'
      ssl: true
      domain: "mail.e-bielsko.net"
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "name@name"
      password: "passwd"
```

It would be nice to know how to run sendmail, but i am delighted that it works now : )